# Hide text boxes based on data in a text field Microsoft Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I am fairly new to Access and i am trying to make a form where the available text boxes depend on the data in a field.

I have made a split form and i would like based on the existing data in the selected line "product" to have the boxes "author" and "date" for books and "type" and "age" for toys.
So if the next product will be a book then i have those two text boxes visible and if it's a toy i have the type and age.

I have made it this far:

```
Private sub Product_Line_AfterUpdate()

Select Case Me.Product_Line.Value
Case "Book"
Me.Type.Visible = False
Me.Age.Visible = False
Else 
Me.Year.Visible = False
Me.Author.Visible = False

End select
```

I'm pretty sure i'm not using "afterupdate" right because basically the field is not being updated, i just change selection on the split form. I tried "onload" but that is not working either.

Thank you

Comment: Might require code in multiple events - such as Current and AfterUpdate. This would not be necessary with Conditional Formatting setting Enabled.